# Bootstrap Responsive IMG Scale to Top Instead of Center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I have a background photo in a Bootstrap template using HTML/CSS. I was wondering if it's possible to make it so on a larger screen, instead of scaling the image and zooming into the center, it zooms into the top?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: This is live at https://chorebug.com/ -- take a look at the header image. As you change the page size, it crops and resizes. But on a large monitor it crops out his head, and I'd like it to crop at the top instead.

Comment: Can you please edit this question with an example of your code? We can't see what you're working with to help you. Thanks!

Comment: @dmanexe I added a link to the site, but it's just using bootstrap <header>

Comment: Let me know if my answer below is helpful!

Comment: do you have access to the css  or you have to override?

Comment: @godfather I have access to css.

Comment: in your css its set to center header.masthead { background: url(../IMG_4126.jpg) no-repeat top ;}

Answer (score 0):

Append the media query for the full-screen size with the following rule:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
     header.masthead {
          background-position: top;
     }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... that didn't quite work. Does it matter where I place the CSS? Shouldn't, right?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the background position of the header image.
For this you can add the `background-position` attribute in the class rule `header.masthead`

```
header.masthead {
    background-position: center top;
}
```

**OR**

You can change the background shorthand to:

```
header.masthead {
    background: url("../IMG_4126.jpg") no-repeat center top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change a property value

**landing-page.css:21**

change this will do what you want
`background : url("../IMG_4126.jpg") no-repeat top center`